# Mediawiki: Show pages with short content

Tags: mediawiki

I have a MediaWiki and would like to list short pages (e.g. with less than 100 characters of wiki-text).

Is there a built-in way to do so or do I have to make a script for this outside of MediaWiki?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Special:ShortPages*. They are ordered by page length.